# intolerance -- as per hindu scriptures, tolerance of the intolerant person or ideology is right action or not?

Tags: scripture, practice, ethics

As per hindu scriptures, tolerating the intolerant person or ideology upto what level is right action ? Should an ascetic on path of meditation, react back with same reverse action ?

Comment: also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/are-all-religions-the-same-or-is-just-hinduism-engulfed-in-the-myth-of-sameness/14122#14122